# A query about the balance of the 42130 - BMW M 1000 RR model

Tags: technic, vehicle, weight

I have reached assembly step 632. The bike has a tendency to lean forward with most of the weight at the front, and is only just staying on the display stand. Has anyone else experienced this issue?

[image: 42130]

Edit:

I have now completed the build and the bike is definitely front loaded and sits with its wheel on the desk and the rear end raised. Again, has anyone else found this issue ?

Here is a picture to illustrate the problem.[image]

Here is another picture to illustrate the problem.[image]

Answer (score 9):

Your front and rear wheel/tires are likely swapped. I didn't realize until I finished the entire set and had the same problem as you. Swapping the front and rear tires solved my issue.

Comment: This is the correct answer, from the picture, the thicker (and hence heavier) wheel is in front while it should be in the back

Comment: @MichaelVerschaeve I think you are right. It looks to me that the fatter wheel is on the front as well. As the front is slightly heavier anyway the swapped wheels add enough weight to tip the model.

Answer (score 3):

I do not have this issue. My model balances fine on that stand.
[image]

There are some elements behind the front wheel I leave out as they keep falling off (only attached on the studs of a couple of half pins) but that should hardly make a difference...

Here's a picture of the bottom of the bike, perhaps you've done something in error there ?

[image]

Comment: I just finished my own build of this one. It is front-heavy, but not enough to tip over. It sits relatively stable on the stand. Those radiator pieces are indeed  irritating. They are only barely attached and kept falling of while attaching the various pieces of fairing around the engine-block. I wonder if replacing the blue half-pins with the creme-colored ones will help. The creme ones have slightly longer studs and maybe a little more grip.